# PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex, expression

i have huge string that i need to separate information. Some parts of it vary and some dont. The difficulty i am facing is that i cant find a symbol or something on which i could get the match i want. So here is the string:

```
$str = "01;01;283;Póvoa do Vâle do Trigo;15315100 01;01;249;Alcafaz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;011;AGADÃO 01;01;2504;Caselho;;;;;;;;;;;3750;012;AGADÃO _ "15" '' ghdhghg AND IT CONTINUES
```

so if we look at the first part of the string (`01;01;283;Póvoa do Vale do Trigo;15315100`), what i want to stay with is:

```
01;01;283
```

and remove the rest of the stuff

in every case, but looking at the first example... :
the 01 is always a number never superior to 2 (not 040 or 150505 or 4075)
the same for the next 01 never superior to 2 (not 405 or 1565 or 425)
then the 283 is the number that can be bigger, it varies (it can be 300 or 17581 or 40755794)

essentially in the end i want only the beginning of each part like:

```
01;01;283
01;01;249
01;01;2504
05,80,104258
94,76,56789124
```

sorry for any misspelling i am Portuguese

---

i forget to say that this separated parts will then go to an array! so the regular expression should not match for example like this:

15315100 01;01;249

so i cant use .+ for example

I AM USING PREG_REPLACE

Comment: `\*\*\*.+\*\*\*;` looks like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(\d+;\d+;\d+)/
```

Should work.

Comment: nop, this is what i want to stay with, and match the rest to remove it

Comment: This will give you the numbers that you have asked for. Try it.

Comment: i want the reverse of this because what i wanht to remove is the text after 01;01;283
01;01;249
01;01;2504
05,80,104258
94,76,56789124

Comment: I AM USING PREG_REPLACE

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. The regex is in the match_all line.

```
$str = "***01;01;283***;Póvoa do Vâle do Trigo;15315100 ***01;01;249***;Alcafaz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;011;AGADÃO ";
preg_match_all("/\*\*\*[01][0-9];[01][0-9];[0-9]*\*\*\*.*?/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: i want the reverse of this because what i wanht to remove is the text after 01;01;283 01;01;249 01;01;2504 05,80,104258 94,76,56789124

Comment: I AM USING PREG_REPLACE

Comment: The code above removes everything other than 01;01;283 01;01;249 01;01;2504 05,80,104258 94,76,56789124 that comes in between. That is what you had asked for right?

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:\d\d;){2}\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yP9pD2)

And maybe it would be easier to just get everything between `***XXX***`

```
\*([\d;]+)\*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qE1cI6)