# PHP preg_replace regular expression separate numbers from the rest

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, expression

I've got a huge string that I need to separate. Some parts of it vary and some don't. The difficulty I am facing is that i cant find a symbol or something on which I can't find the match I want to use with preg_replace because it is all alphanumeric. Here is the string:

`$str = "01;01;283;Póvoa do Vale do Trigo;15315100 
01;01;249;Alcafaz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;011;AGADÃO 
01;01;2504;Caselho;;;;;;;;;;;3750;012;AGADÃO _ 15 '' ghdhghg 
01;01;25155;Corga da Serra;;;;;;;;;;;3750;013;AGADÃO 01;01;252;Foz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;014;AGADÃO 
01;01;253;Guistola;;;;;;;;;;;3750;015;AGADÃO 01;01;254;Guistolinha;;;;;;;;;;;3750;016;AGADÃO 
01;01;255;Lomba;;;;;;;;;;;3750;017;AGADÃO AND IT CONTINUES ...";`

So if we look at the first part of the string (`01;01;283;Póvoa do Vale do Trigo;15315100`), what I want to keep is:

`01;01;283;`

and match:

`;Póvoa do Vale do Trigo;15315100`

and replace with space.

In the end I want to have this:

`01;01;283 01;01;249 01;01;2504; 01;01;25155 01;01;252 01;01;253 01;01;254 01;01;255`

after I have replaced:

`;Póvoa do Vale do Trigo;15315100
;Alcafaz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;011;AGADÃO
;Caselho;;;;;;;;;;;3750;012;AGADÃO _ 15 '' ghdhghg
;Corga da Serra;;;;;;;;;;;3750;013;AGADÃO
;Foz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;014;AGADÃO
;Guistola;;;;;;;;;;;3750;015;AGADÃO
;Guistolinha;;;;;;;;;;;3750;016;AGADÃO 
;Lomba;;;;;;;;;;;3750;017;AGADÃO`

by `""`

Sorry for any misspelling I am Portuguese.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529922/php-regular-expression)

Comment: Show us what you've tried with preg_replace and we will maybe help

Comment: csv ? can you explain better

Comment: You could work with each line as array by using `explode` or `str_getcsv`

Comment: I TRIED THIS ------>  ;\D+\d{4};\d{3};.{0,100}\s{1}

Comment: please somebody help me with this, this is so important!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?:[0-9]+;?){3}\K;.+?(?=(?>[0-9]+;){3}|$)~s', ' ', $str);
```

The idea is to match the 3 numbers and remove them from the match result using `\K`. Then, you match all with `.+?` until the next 3 numbers or the end of string.

An other pattern you can try:

```
$result = preg_replace('~;[^0-9].+?(?=(?>[0-9]+;){3}|$)~s', ' ', $str);
```

Comment: thank you very much ;) that worked! i've been around this for hours!

Comment: this is precisely what worked:
[0-9]+;[0-9]+;[0-9]+;\K.+?(?=[0-9]+;[0-9]+;[0-9]|$)
but it came from your code ;)

Comment: @user2909037: the udapted version works too (it's the same, but shorter)

Comment: the use o \k was really important, i tryed something that could do the same but never find anything... didn't even knew that \k existed!

"What this handy sequence does is resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence."

Comment: @user2909037: Yes `\K` isn't well known in general. But you can avoid it with: `'~((?:[0-9]+;?){3});.+?(?=(?>[0-9]+;){3}|$)~s'` and `'$1 '`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:

```
$str = "01;01;283;Póvoa do Vale do Trigo;15315100 
01;01;249;Alcafaz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;011;AGADÃO 
01;01;2504;Caselho;;;;;;;;;;;3750;012;AGADÃO _ 15 '' ghdhghg 
01;01;25155;Corga da Serra;;;;;;;;;;;3750;013;AGADÃO 01;01;252;Foz;;;;;;;;;;;3750;014;AGADÃO 
01;01;253;Guistola;;;;;;;;;;;3750;015;AGADÃO 01;01;254;Guistolinha;;;;;;;;;;;3750;016;AGADÃO 
01;01;255;Lomba;;;;;;;;;;;3750;017;AGADÃO AND IT CONTINUES ...";

$str2 = preg_replace('/^([0-9]+;[0-9]+;[0-9]+).*[\r\n]+/m', '$1 ', $str."\n");

echo $str2;
```

output:

```
01;01;283 01;01;249 01;01;2504 01;01;25155 01;01;253 01;01;255
```